# Why my ListView databinding to observable collection don't show correctly

Tags: c#, sqlite, data-binding, uwp

[image: how is showing the data actually]

this is my class TaskTodo and the method GetTask this method connect with sqlite and return a observable collection

```
using Microsoft.Data.Sqlite;
using System;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.IO;
using Windows.Storage;

namespace uwp_to_do_list
{
public class TaskTodo : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public string NameTask { get; set; }
    public DateTime Reminder { get; set; }
    public string NameList { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public string SubTask { get; set; }
    public string Priority { get; set; }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    public ObservableCollection<TaskTodo> GetTasks()
    {
        var Tasks = new ObservableCollection<TaskTodo>();
        //get data from sqlite3

        string dbpath = Path.Combine(ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path, "TasksSqlite.db");
        using (SqliteConnection db =
           new SqliteConnection($"Filename={dbpath}"))
        {
            db.Open();

            SqliteCommand selectCommand = new SqliteCommand
                ("SELECT Name_task from Task", db);

            SqliteDataReader query = selectCommand.ExecuteReader();

            while (query.Read())
            {
               TaskTodo taskTodo = new TaskTodo();
                taskTodo.NameTask = query.GetString(0);
                Tasks.Add(taskTodo);
            }

            db.Close();
        }


        return Tasks;
    }
```

so i put this observable collection as the itemsource of listview,  but this just show  the type of the object not the field NameTask.

```
public MainView()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        TaskTodo taskTodo = new TaskTodo();
        task_list.ItemsSource = taskTodo.GetTasks()
        Debug.WriteLine(taskTodo.GetTasks()[4].NameTask);


    }
```

i think the problem is in the xaml code because went i tested if the observable collection is empty

```
Debug.WriteLine(taskTodo.GetTasks()[4].NameTask);
```

the outpuy was tasxk3

my xaml code

```
   <Page
    x:Class="uwp_to_do_list.MainView"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:uwp_to_do_list"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup- 
    compatibility/2006" xmlns:fa="using:FontAwesome.UWP"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Background="#08090A"       
    >

    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"></ColumnDefinition>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="auto"></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
           <StackPanel Background="#04000E" Width="240"  
            Grid.Column="0" 
            Grid.Row="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" >

            <TextBlock Text="today" Foreground="White" FontSize="24" 
            HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,50,0,0"> 
             </TextBlock>
            <fa:FontAwesome Icon="CalendarCheckOutline" Height="40" 
             Width="40" FontSize="40" Foreground="Fuchsia" 
             HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="20,-35,0,0"> 
            </fa:FontAwesome>
            <TextBlock Text="Tomorrow" Foreground="White" 
             FontSize="24" HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
              Margin="0,20,0,0"></TextBlock>
            <fa:FontAwesome Icon="CalendarOutline" Height="40" 
             Width="40" FontSize="40" Foreground="Fuchsia" 
             HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="20,-35,0,0"> 
            </fa:FontAwesome>
            <TextBlock Text="planning" Foreground="White" 
              FontSize="24" HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
             Margin="0,20,0,0"></TextBlock>
            <fa:FontAwesome Icon="Calendar" Height="40" Width="40" 
             FontSize="40" Foreground="Fuchsia" 
             HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="20,-35,0,0"> 
             </fa:FontAwesome>
            <TextBlock Text="tasks" Foreground="White" FontSize="24" 
            HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,20,0,0"> 
            </TextBlock>
            <fa:FontAwesome Icon="Home" Height="40" Width="40" 
            FontSize="40" Foreground="Fuchsia" 
            HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="20,-35,0,0"> 
            </fa:FontAwesome>

        </StackPanel>

        <TextBox  Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
        Grid.Column="0" Text="+ add a list " Background="#04000E" 
        Foreground="White" Height="50" Width="240" ></TextBox>
        <TextBox x:Name="add_Task_textbox" Grid.Row="1" 
        Grid.Column="1" KeyDown="add_Task_textbox_KeyDown"  
        HorizontalAlignment="Center"    VerticalAlignment="Center" 
        Text="+ add a task"  Background="#04000E" Foreground="White" 
        Height="40" Width="1000" Margin="20,0,-20,0" />
        <ListView x:Name="task_list" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" 
        Background="Transparent">

        <ListViewItem>

          <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:TaskTodo">
           
           <TextBlock Width="100" Foreground="White" Text="{x:Bind 
            NameTask}"></TextBlock>
           
           </DataTemplate>
     
            </ListViewItem>
   
       
             </ListView>
       
        
          </Grid>
        </Page>
```

for more context [my github repository](https://github.com/KelvinJPS/todolist-uwp/tree/master)

Comment: You are setting a list of TaskTodo as the ItemSource. You need some way to transform the instances of this class in the string that represent them. One way is to override the ToString() method inside the TaskToDoc class and return the string you want to see in the ListView items

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set the `ItemTemplate` property to your `DataTemplate` instead of adding a `ListViewItem`:

```
<ListView x:Name="task_list" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" 
          Background="Transparent">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:TaskTodo">
            <TextBlock Width="100" Foreground="White"
                       Text="{x:Bind NameTask}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```